# baffled with the integral $\int_0^1{e^x \over e^x+1} \, dx$

Tags: integration

> Calculate:
>   $$I=\int_0^1{e^x\over e^x+1}dx$$

**Personal work:**

$$I=\int_0^1{e^x\over e^x+1}dx$$
Let $u=e^x$ hence ${du\over e^x}=dx$

So, $$I=\int_1^e {e^x\over u+1}{du\over e^x}=\int _1^e {1\over u+1}\,du=\cdots$$
I've thought of getting rid of the $u+1$ at the bottom of the fraction, so, $$I=\int_1^e (u+1)^{-1} \, du$$
The problem is this: the anti-derivative of any monomial is given by this type: $$x^n={x^{n+1}\over n+1}+C, C\in \mathbb R.$$ The problem is that $-1+1=0$.

Comment: $\int x^{-1}\, dx = \ln|x| +C$

Answer (score 2):

You could apply $u$ substitution by letting $u=e^x+1$, and $du=e^x dx$, this yields, $$\int \frac{du}{u}=\ln(u)=\ln(e^x+1)+C$$

Answer (score 1):

The derivative of $\ln(1+x)$ is ${1\over{x+1}}$

Answer (score 1):

Let $$u=e^x+1$$

$$I=\int_0^1{e^x\over e^x+1}dx = \int_2^{e+1}{du\over u}=$$

$$ \ln(e+1)-\ln(2) = \ln (\frac {e+1}{2})$$

Answer (score 1):

Another approach:
$$
\begin{align}
\int_0^1\frac{e^x}{e^x+1}\,\mathrm{d}x
&=\int_0^1\frac1{1+e^{-x}}\,\mathrm{d}x\tag1\\
&=\int_0^1\sum_{k=0}^\infty(-1)^ke^{-kx}\,\mathrm{d}x\tag2\\
&=\sum_{k=0}^\infty(-1)^k\int_0^1e^{-kx}\,\mathrm{d}x\tag3\\
&=1+\sum_{k=1}^\infty(-1)^k\frac1k\left(1-e^{-k}\right)\tag4\\
&=1-\log(2)+\log\left(1+\frac1e\right)\tag5\\[3pt]
&=\log\left(\frac{e+1}2\right)\tag6
\end{align}
$$
Explanation:
$(1)$: divide numerator and denominator by $e^x$
$(2)$: use the geometric series for $\frac1{1+x}=\sum\limits_{k=0}^\infty x^k$
$(3)\vphantom{\sum\limits_1}$: change order of summation and integration (allowed because the series converges absolutely)
$(4)$: evaluate the integrals (separating the term for $k=0$)
$(5)$: use the series for $\log(1+x)=\sum\limits_{k=1}^\infty(-1)^{k-1}\frac{x^k}k$
$(6)$: combine the terms

Comment: That seems too complex to solve an easy integral where you could just set $u=e^x+1$. However, at what kind of problems could the sum series be helpful at?

Comment: Yes, I agree that this is not the simplest approach, but it's not an unreasonable one and offers an alternative when the other substitution doesn't come to mind. As far as the sum series, I will look through a number of answers and find some where the series is a simpler approach. It might be that there may always be a better approach, but this can still be a useful tool.

Comment: Well, I would ask you why you put $k\to +\infty$ and why you wrote this and that but I think it would be a waste of time to explain me. Sum series look hard and I can't seem to find any distinguishable pattern, as far as, the $(-1)^k$ etc. Though, I do see that are more ways to approach a mathematical problem even if they're more complicated.

Comment: I'm sorry you didn't find the answer useful. I've added some explanations for the steps in case that proves useful for anyone.

Answer (score 0):

Hint: the solution is given by $$\int\frac{e^x}{e^x+1}dx=\log(1+e^x)+C$$

Answer (score 0):

$$I = \big[\ln (u +1)\big]_{1}^{e} = \ln \frac{e+1}{2}$$

Comment: My typing is so slow, that all other answers are there. :-)

Comment: It's okay, thanks though